# Saving file as copy in C++ plugin for Adobe InDesign SC6 SDK

Tags: plugins, adobe, adobe-indesign

I am working on C++ plugin for Adobe InDesign SC6 SDK.
I am trying to save a file as a copy. 
A file was created manually in InDesign and it's open.

The method docFileHandler->CanSaveACopy(documentUIDRef) from the code below returns false.

How can I check why my document cannot be saved?
I did not find the answer in documentation and don't have a source code for CanSaveAs() method.

Please, advise.

```
ErrorCode result = kFailure;
do {
    // Save the document to another file.
    UIDRef documentUIDRef(db, persist->GetUID());

    InterfacePtr<IDocFileHandler> docFileHandler(Utils<IDocumentUtils>()->QueryDocFileHandler(documentUIDRef));
    if (!docFileHandler) {
        break;
    }

    std::string urlToCopy("C:\\temp\\test.indd.bak");
    FileId theCopyFileId;
    theCopyFileId.SetFileURL(urlToCopy);

    if(docFileHandler->CanSaveACopy(documentUIDRef) ) {
        docFileHandler->SaveACopy (documentUIDRef, &theCopyFileId);
        result = ErrorUtils::PMGetGlobalErrorCode();

        if (result != kSuccess) {
            break;
        }
    }
} while(false);
```

Comment: Couldn't your problem be linked to the urlToCopy specification and especially the trailing '.bak' ?

Comment: The method CanSaveACopy() , that returns false, does not get the url.. it only gets the reference to the origin document